# CSS display inline and float are not working inside a wrapper

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where I want to display two wrappers next to each other.
I specifically want to put the moving shape next to the text.
The pen is here: https://codepen.io/jlanssie/pen/xxZaaJW
However, I cannot seem to get it to work.

```css
    * {
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    body {
      overflow: hidden; 
      background-color: #111;
      color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    wrapper {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .logoWrapper {
      margin: 1em auto; 
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
    }
    
    .logoImgWrapper, .logoTxtWrapper {
      display: inline;
    }
    
    #logo {
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      
      animation-name: logoTransformation;
      animation-duration: 5s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    
    @keyframes logoTransformation {
      0% {
        background-color: rgba(48,255,144,1);
      }
    
      25% {
        border-radius: 50%;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        background-color: rgba(237,45,237,1);
      }
    
      50% {
        border-radius: 0%;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        background-color: rgba(201,152,38,1);
      }
    
      75% {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: rgba(48,255,230,1);
      }
    
      100% {
        background-color: rgba(48,255,144,1);
      } 
    }
```

```html
<wrapper class="logoWrapper">
      <wrapper class="logoCenterWrapper">
        <wrapper class="logoImgWrapper">
          <div id="logo"></div>
        </wrapper>
        <wrapper class="logoTxtWrapper">
          <p class="site-title">GrawR</p>
        </wrapper>
      </wrapper>
</wrapper>
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?
I have also tried with floats, but no luck there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out.
I had to delete the margin: 0 auto; and height and width properties in the main logoWrapper and replace that by a text-align: center. Now it works well.

Answer (score 0):

All I did was add `display: flex;` to `.logoCenterWrapper` and that will put the 2 next to eachother

see this site for more information on flexbox
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden; 
  background-color: #111;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

wrapper {
  display: block;
}

.logoWrapper {
  margin: 1em auto; 
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.logoCenterWrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.logoImgWrapper, .logoTxtWrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

#logo {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  
  animation-name: logoTransformation;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes logoTransformation {
  0% {
    background-color: rgba(48,255,144,1);
  }

  25% {
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background-color: rgba(237,45,237,1);
  }

  50% {
    border-radius: 0%;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    background-color: rgba(201,152,38,1);
  }

  75% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(48,255,230,1);
  }

  100% {
    background-color: rgba(48,255,144,1);
  } 
}

.site-title {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<wrapper class="logoWrapper">
  <wrapper class="logoCenterWrapper">
    <wrapper class="logoImgWrapper">
      <div id="logo"></div>
    </wrapper>
    <wrapper class="logoTxtWrapper">
      <div class="site-title">GrawR</div>
    </wrapper>
  </wrapper>
</wrapper>
```